# A Term for a writer producing a lot content

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

This might be a very straightforward question. I am looking for a word to describe an author who is going through a very creating phase and is churning out a lot of work. I am unable to recollect a very commonly used adjective for this. Usage might look like:

> From 1905 to 1908 he published several short stories and novels. He was a very _______ writer during that time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The particular word that fits the blank there is [***prolific***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prolific)¹.

If it’s a sustained, and especially unique, period you might call it their [***golden***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/golden)² years or [***golden age***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/golden-age)¹ (sometimes capitalised).

---

¹ [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/).

² [Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/).

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't remember prolific :)

Comment: It's often hard to search for a word using the meaning, otherwise this site probably wouldn't get half the traffic it does.

Answer (score 2):

> A [prolific writer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/prolific), artist, or composer **produces a large number of works**.

Prolific is a very commonly used adjective for this.

Comment: Sorry, had to give it to the first one to answer it.

Comment: It is possible to wait awhile to see if there's a "better" answer :o)

Comment: You answered the question sufficiently and a little sooner, so you definitely deserve the reward.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider "copious" if perhaps it was the volume of his works produced but not the most fruitful of his works.